# failure in retriving json file using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I get a json file when call a web service.

I am trying to retrive data using jquery and show on html5 page.
I do get json file when i open in a browser say: SampleURI.

```
    {"employeeList":[{"birthDate":"1948-12-08T00:00:00-07:00","city":"Seattle","firstName":"Nancy","lastName":"Davolio","title":"Accountant"},{"birthDate":"1948-12-08T00:00:00-07:00","city":"Seattle","firstName":"Nancy","lastName":"Davolio","title":"Accountant"}]}
```

here is my script:

```
    $(document).ready(
        function() {$("#btnJson").click(function() {
                    var rootURL = "SampleURI";
                        $.ajax({
                                        type: "GET",
                                        url: rootURL,
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        data: "",
                                        success: renderList, // renderlist is function which display table
                            error: function() { alert("Failure");}
                                    });

                                 }//end function
                         );//end click    
        }//end function
);//end document
```

This give me Failure message.

I am new to jquery, so could anyone tell where i am going wrong.

Comment: Is your browser outputting any errors to its console? This is the best place to look first.

Comment: Open up Firebug or another debugger, look for console error, and check the NET/XHR tab and see what is being passed back and forth in the request.

Comment: More than likely SampleURI is of a different domain than the page that is requesting the JSON, causing it to get caught by the same-origin policy. If that is the case, research **JSONP**

Comment: SampleURI is of different domain. I tried using jsonp datatype.still it doesn't work.

Comment: giving jsonp datatype isn't enough : if this is the URI of a JSON service, the server won't answer in JSONP.

Comment: The URI is JSON Webservice which returns JSON object. I am trying to parse it using jquery and display on HTML page. The same code works if it is executed in same domain.

Answer (score 0):

**JSON** is not allowed cross-domain unless the server implements **CORS**.

**JSONP** is allowed cross-domain, however the server has to implement **JSONP**.

If neither of the above are possible, your only option is to create a server-side proxy local to your file that makes the request for you and returns the data.

To test for JSONP support, go to

`SampleURI.com?jsonpcallback=foo`
or
`SampleURI.com?callback=foo`
the json returned should then be wrapped in `foo(thejson)`